# Module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols, qt5.3

I'm trying to compile some qml on a Raspberry pi 3 running Raspbian-Jessie using qt5 (5.3.2).
I managed to run some simple stuff but now I need to use QtQuick.Controls so I added
`import QtQuick.Controls 1.0` to my qml file but when I try to run it, I get this error message: `module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed`
Qt is installed in the following folder `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/` (it's auto detected) so I went there and found that QtQuick Controls is actually in there (in `[path to qt]/qml/QtQuick/Controls`)

Do I need to do something to actually install it ?
I tried to add `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/QtQuick/Controls` to `QML_IMPORT_PATH` but I still get the error message.
I also read that I need QtQuick 2.0 for QtQuick.Controls to work but when I change `import QtQuick 1.0` to `import QtQuick 2.0` I get a `module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed`
Anyone managed to use QtQuick.Controls on Raspberry Pi ?
Any advice on how to debug this ?

Answer (score 8):

Dependencies for QML in Raspbian are somewhat confusing. Try checking if you have these packages installed, using `apt-get install`, or `apt-cache search` first to see what every single package does:

```
qtdeclarative5-*
qml-module-qtquick*
qtquick1-*
qtquickcontrols5-*
qml-module-qtquick2
```

After that, Qt Creator should compile without problems.